# Google Chrome multiple favicons

Tags: google-chrome, favicon

So on google chrome and its only on google chrome I can't seem to get my favicon for a specific page to work

I have a default favicon in the root directory call favicon.ico but I have another one called Lokor_favicon.ico the code im using for the specific page is as follows

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Lokor_favicon.ico?v=2" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="/Lokor_favicon.ico?v=2" type="image/x-icon">
```

on fire fox it can load the two different favicons based off what page I am on but on chrome it simply refuses to follow the code and goes with the default favicon anyways

any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Chrome isn't trying to be difficult, there's just no defined way to handle multiple favicons, and each browser implements their own approach. The wikipedia article explains this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#How_to_use

Here's the pertinent info:

> If links for both PNG and ICO favicons are present, PNG-favicon-compatible browsers select which format and size to use as follows. Firefox and Safari will use the favicon that comes last. Chrome for Mac will use whichever favicon is ICO formatted, otherwise the 32×32 favicon. Chrome for Windows will use the favicon that comes first if it is 16×16, otherwise the ICO. If none of the aforementioned options are available, both Chromes will use whichever favicon comes first, exactly the opposite of Firefox and Safari. Indeed, Chrome for Mac will ignore the 16×16 favicon and use the 32×32 version if only to scale it back down to 16×16 on non-retina devices. Opera will choose from any of the available icons completely at random.

It's best to only offer one favicon. If you have a larger PNG version that you specify in your meta tags, then skip using the favicon.ico file altogether. All browsers will support that.

If you feel you need multiple icons for different parts of your site, then you're trying to use them in a way they were never intended, and you'll have mixed results. If you remove the favicon.ico file altogether, and instead let each page specify its own icon, then people will end up seeing the icon for the first page they visit. So if they get to your "about us" page from Google, they're going to see whatever icon the "about us" page specifies, for the duration of their visit and as long as their browser stores it in cache.

Comment: the thing is they are both ico favicons and the point off the current website I am creating is to essential be a personal website for the "host" through my website Example MyWebsite.com/You

What I don't understand is why google doesn't listen to the code telling it what favicon to use.  No matter what page I start on it uses the default favicon even though I have one specified for the page

Comment: A domain is expected to have a single favicon, period. it's not expected to have different icons on different pages. And I don't know if any browser is going to update the favicon for the site once it thinks it already has the icon. So if somebody visits mywebsite.com/you, sees your icon, then visits mywebsite.com/me, they're still going to see your icon.  You're trying to use icons in a way they weren't meant to be used. Try using subdomains instead (me.mywebsite.com, you.mywebsite.com) and that will solve your issue.